# XML node is missing when empty

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, nodes

I have an `XMLDocument` as result of query.

I would like to extract the `<Property>` value and the appropriate `<Notes>` for each entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EADATA version="1.0" exporter="Enterprise Architect">
<Dataset_0>
    <Data>
      <Row>
        <PropertyID>439</PropertyID>
        <Object_ID>683</Object_ID>
        <Property>tagged value</Property>
        <ea_guid>{5BF3E019-277B-45c2-B2DE-1887A90C6944}</ea_guid>
      </Row>


      <Row> 
        <PropertyID>444</PropertyID>
        <Object_ID>683</Object_ID>
        <Property>Another Tagged value</Property>
        <Notes>Another tagged value notes.</Notes>
        <ea_guid>{42BE8BAA-06B8-4822-B79A-59F653C44453}</ea_guid>
      </Row>
    </Data>
  </Dataset_0>
</EADATA>
```

However, If the `<Notes>` is empty there is no `<Notes>` tag at all.

What `XPath` should I write in such cases?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you desire as output. So there is no `<Nodes>` element, so what do you want to output? Maybe some expected output for the given example would help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which value do you want if there is no `Notes` element, a null, an empty string?

I would select the `Row` elements with `SelectNodes` and then check whether a `Notes` child exists and assign null (as done below) or the empty string if not:

```
foreach (XmlElement row in doc.SelectNodes("//Row"))
{
  string prop = row.SelectSingleNode("Property").InnerText;
  string notes = row.SelectSingleNode("Notes") != null ? row.SelectSingleNode("Notes").InnerText : null;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice solution. I wonder however what's the difference vs my solution. can u elaborate ? ( im talking about the classes usage. not the xpath string itself)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I took "XMLDocument" as meaning `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and posted code using that DOM API in the .NET framework. You used a different API with XPathDocument/XPathNavigator and additionally XDocument. The .NET framework has grown over the years to contain different APIs for XML processing so your solution is fine of course as well although I wouldn't use both XPathDocument and XDocument together, I would solely use either XPathDocument or XDocument, mixing them does not seem necessary.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes , But how would you "digest" the `selectedNode` in my  `foreach (XPathNavigator selectedNode in NodeIter)` ?  I tried to access the properties inside it , but with no success...( that's why I added the XDocument)

Comment: You can use `foreach (XPathNavigator row in navigator.Select("/EADATA/Dataset_0/Data/Row") { string prop = row.SelectSingleNode("Property").Value; string notes = row.SelectSingleNode("Notes") != null ? row.SelectSingleNode("Notes").Value : null }`.

Comment: ouch... missed the `SelectSingleNode` method ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
XPathNavigator navigator = docNav.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter = navigator.Select("/EADATA/Dataset_0/Data/Row"); 

foreach (XPathNavigator selectedNode in NodeIter) 
{
    var a=  "<root>" +  selectedNode.InnerXml + "</root>";
    var x= XDocument.Parse(a);
    Console.WriteLine (x.Root.Element("Property").Value); 
    if (x.Root.Element("Notes")!=null)
    Console.WriteLine (x.Root.Element("Notes").Value); 

}
```

result :

```
tagged value
Another Tagged value
Another tagged value notes.
```